# What Version of Foundation Am I using? (NodeJS/Grunt)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, git-bash

I am new to using both NodeJS and Grunt and I am trying to figure out how I can find what version of Foundation I am using. I have been checking random files such as my "Gruntfile" and using the keyword "foundation" hoping I can find something such as `src=*foundation*` which would contain a version number, but I am having no luck.

Is there is a quick way using either GitBash or Node.js command prompt to find my Foundation version, or by looking at another file?

P.S. I have tried random file locations using the command "foundation version" with no luck either on both of the above prompts.

Comment: If you installed it with npm locally, it would be in your package.json, and in the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about http://foundation.zurb.com/ ?, i dont think that you can find it via NodeJS/Grunt Cmd lines.

If you use bower, it may have the version in bower.json while installing.

Comment: Cool, so I looked in bower.json and got this. `"angular-foundation": "latest"`, does this mean it is just grabbing whatever the latest version of Foundation is from their site?

Answer (score 1):

Foundation adds a global object, `Foundation` in which you'll find the parameter `version`.

Print it as debug parameter in you javascript or fire up your browser javascript console and type:

```
Foundation.version
```